# Combining VTP versions 2 and 3 in a network

Tags: vtp

Some of our switches only support VTP Version 2,
  Can it be used on a simultaneous network of versions 2 and 3 together?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

It depends, if the VTP server is running version 2, it will automatically set all clients to version 2. If that is not possible, the client will not work and it will stand as a mismatch. You cannot change VTP version on a client, as the server will force the version of what it is running.

VTP version 3 supports all the features in version 1 and version 2. VTP version 3 also supports the following features not supported in version 1 and version 2:

- Enhanced authentication—In VTP version 3, you can configure the
  authentication password to be hidden using the vtp password command.
  When you configure the authentication password to be hidden, it does
  not appear in plain text in the configuration. Instead, the secret
  associated with the password is saved in hexadecimal format in the
  running configuration. The password-string argument is an ASCII
  string from 1 to 64 characters identifying the administrative domain
  for the device.

  The hidden and secret keywords for VTP password are supported only in
  VTP version 3. If converting to VTP version 2 from VTP version 3, you
  must remove the hidden or secret keyword prior to the conversion.
  These keywords are supported on the Catalyst 6500 series switch only.
- Support for extended range VLAN database propagation—VTP version 1
  and version 2 support VLANs 1 to 1000 only. In VTP version 3, the
  entire VLAN range is supported (VLANs 1 to 4094). The pruning of
  VLANs still applies to VLANs 1 to 1000 only. Extended-range VLANs are
  supported in VTP version 3 only. Private VLANs are supported in VTP
  version 3. If you convert from VTP version 3 to VTP version 2, the
  VLANs in the range 1006 to 4094 are removed from VTP control.
- VLANs 1002 to 1005 are reserved VLANs in VTP version 1, version 2,
  and version 3.
- Support for propagation of any database in a domain—In VTP version 1
  and version 2, a VTP server is used to back up the database to the
  NVRAM and allows you to change the database information.

Source: https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/switches/lan/catalyst6500/ios/12-2SX/configuration/guide/book/vtp.html